# executing a function after completing parent function in javascript by callback

Tags: javascript

I have a function `foo`, which takes another function as argument. i want the function which i pass to `foo` as argument will run after finishing all the tasks of `foo`. My Javascript code is:

```
function foo(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("This will come first.");
               }, 2000);

    func();
}

foo( function(){console.log("This will come later.");} );
```

My desired output(in the console of browser) is like:

```
This will come first.     
This will come later.
```

But i get the output of above code as below:

```
This will come later.
This will come first.
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: we had that one yesterday already

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `func()` inside your timeout.

```
function foo(func) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("This will come first.");
        func();
    }, 2000);


}

foo(function() {
    console.log("This will come later.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `callback` to inside `setTimeout()`

```
function foo(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
          console.log("This will come first.");
          func();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you register a `setTimeout`, an event is registered to be executed at certain time and remaining code is continued to execute. You should call your function inside `setTimeout`

```js
function foo(func) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("This will come first.");
    func();   // Call here
  }, 2000);

  //func();  // Not here
}

foo(function() {
  console.log("This will come later.");
});
```